# How to change templates for Angular 1.4 New Router based on dynamic params?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-new-router

I have the following $router configuration

```
$router.config ([
      { path: '/account/profile', components: {'main' : 'accountProfile' }},
      { path: '/campaigns/:type', components: {'main' : 'campaigns' }},
      { path: '/login', components: {'main' : 'login' }},
      { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' }
  ]);
```

and I want to change template for campaigns based on their :type.

How can I do this using the new Angular Router?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write your own [TemplateMapping function - line 570](https://github.com/angular/router/blob/master/src/router-directive.es5.js) and return the templatename depending on the request params.